# Sphinx search on multiple indexes with different attributes

Tags: php, filter, attributes, sphinx

Is it possible to search on multiple indexes with different attributes and keep consistent PAGIN.

For example we have 2 indexes:

1. Places with GEO data
2. Objects without GEO data

And we want to to apply GEO filters for index #1(SetFilterFloatRange, SetGeoAnchor) and SKIP this filter for index #2. We want to show these results in one result set with one paging.

Is it possible with SPHINX?

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not currently possible - you will receive an error if you try to do so.

The workaround for this would be to have the same field inside the index #2, but with some value, which indicates that this check should be skipped.

Your search query might look like this: `(@somefield ("%s") | @somefield ("NONE"))`, where `NONE` is your "empty value" and `%s` is the string you are actually looking for.